# how to display the y-values on the top of each bar of the seaborn bargraph?

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to generate the bargraph as the below:

```py
# generate the bargraphs based on the `stat_list_prop`
def plot_bargraph_min_error(stat_list_prop, bar_color):

    plt.xlabel("Layer")
    plt.ylabel('Probability of Producing the Minimal Error')    
    sns.barplot(x=[x+1 for x in range(7)], y = stat_list_prop, color = bar_color)

stat_list_prop=[0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.2]

# generates a bargraph without the numbers
plot_bargraph_min_error(stat_list_prop,'green')
```

But I want to display the y-values on the top of each bar of the bargraph that I made. For example, the first bar has the height of 0.5, so I would like the number 0.5 to be displayed on the top of the first bar of my bargraph.

How can I do this? Because I am using a seaborn bargraph, I am not sure how to go about this.

What I want is similar to the image below, except I want the vertical bargraph, not the horizontal bargraph

[image]
Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# generate the bargraphs based on the `stat_list_prop`
def plot_bargraph_min_error(stat_list_prop, bar_color):

    plt.xlabel("Layer")
    plt.ylabel('Probability of Producing the Minimal Error')    
    sns.barplot(x=[x+1 for x in range(7)], y = stat_list_prop, color = bar_color)

    # text legends on each bar
    for n,i in enumerate(stat_list_prop): 
        plt.text(n,i, str(i))   


# Your defined list 
stat_list_prop=[0.5,0.1,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.9,0.2]
 
# generates a bargraph without the numbers
plot_bargraph_min_error(stat_list_prop,'green')
```

Comment: I want each number to be displayed directly above each bar, not at the top of the window

Comment: raise ValueError(f"Grouper for '{t}' not 1-dimensional")

Comment: How the data that you used is different from the example? Are you using a multidimensional array? It's probably because you can't convert such data to text.

Comment: the x-axis is all wrong, the x ticks are on the top of the window, while I want it along the x-axis

Comment: `plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = True` `plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = False` or restart the kernel